# How do I switch to top view but upside down?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

When I press <kbd>7</kbd>, the view is as I need it.
However, I would want it upside down.

Here is a screenshot of what I got and what I need.

How could I do this without actually rotating my model? Is would it be too complicated, and rotating my model around is way easier?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the following setting in my Preferences > Keymap:

[image]

..which lets me roll my view with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Mouse Wheel Up</kbd> / <kbd>Mouse Wheel Down</kbd>. The roll can be levelled at any time with one of the preset <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>[x]</kbd> views.

Answer (score 4):

You can press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to switch to top view and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> twelve (12) times to rotate perfectly upside down. Also check the official [`Navigating Documentation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/index.html). Here's a list of other hotkeys. Note that the numbers are all Numpad keys.

| Hotkey | Description |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>1</kbd> | Front view |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> | Back view |
| <kbd>2</kbd> | Rotate view up |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> | Pan view up |
| <kbd>3</kbd> | Left side view |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> | Right side view |
| <kbd>4</kbd> | Rotate view left |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> | Pan view left |
| <kbd>5</kbd> | Toggle perspective / orthographic view |
| <kbd>6</kbd> | Rotate view right |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> | Pan view right |
| <kbd>7</kbd> | Top view |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> | Bottom view |
| <kbd>8</kbd> | Rotate view down |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> | Pan view down |
| <kbd>9</kbd> | Redraw screen |
| <kbd>0</kbd> | Camera view |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> | Set camera to viewport |
| <kbd>/</kbd> | Toggle local view |
| <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (dot / period) | Zoom on selection |
| <kbd>+</kbd> | Zoom into view |